# Standard scalar in java like numpy

Tags: java, numpy, tensorflow

I am loading a pre trained model into android using tensorflow

in my original model , whenever I tried to predict something I need to put the array using `StandardScaler`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()

model.predict(sc.transform(np.array([[6,5,2,5]])))
```

In my android part , I am giving input as float array

```
float[] input = new float[]{6,5,2,5};
```

Which show inaccurate result , but if I put

```
 float[] input = new float[]{-0.45480626,  0.00226552 ,-1.23735555 ,-0.17786957};
```

It show accurate result

here

```
print(sc.transform(np.array([[6,5,2,5]])));
>>[[-0.45480626  0.00226552 -1.23735555 -0.17786957]]
```

How can I use numpy like standard scalar in java

Comment: Well, if it is okay with the model, change the floats to 6.001f, 5.01f etc and see if it makes a difference. Maybe there is something wrong with the model?

Comment: @jrook it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: In that case, I would search for the problem elsewhere. Seems like floats are doing their job. You can try doubles too to see if it makes a difference

Comment: (1) it is `StandardScaler()` not standard scalar. Please fix your question accordingly; (2) are you looking for a way of using Python's `StandardScaler()` within Java (if so, can you show your glue code) OR are you looking for an equivalent of `StandardScaler()` in Java (in which case you could look at `StandardScaler()` source code)?

Comment: @norok2  I am looking for java equivalent for `StandardScaler()`

Comment: What version of `sklearn` are you using? It looks like what you expect as result of `StandardScaler()` is (1) wrong; (2) not working without calling `fit()` first; (3) different from what I have obtained with version 0.19.2.

Comment: I am using sklearn version 0.19.1 .

Comment: @mW3 Nothing seems to have changed with respect to `StandardScaler()`? In principle, `StandardScaler()` produces a pre-whitened version of a signal by doing: `(x - m) / s` where `x` is the signal, `m` is the mean and `s` is the std.deviation. If I use `StandardScaler()` with `x` for the `.fit()`, I get exactly that (and you could reproduce it with Java very easily). But this is different from what you show, and I do not now how to get to your output, and the code you have reported so far does not work the same way for me. See [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).